# Logging a Jetty SSL Client Certificate Issue

Tags: maven-2, ssl, jetty

I am trying to configure Jetty (via the jetty-maven-plugin) to use client certificates. I have it working (somewhat) without the client certificate, but with the  set to yes, absolutely nothing happens.

What I need to know is how to configure Jetty to log its startup and operation to try to figure out the issue. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. The answer is to run maven with the -X parameter:

maven -X jetty:run